# How to use default order on a functional field with store = False Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9

I work with Odoo9 using the old API and I found myself in a tricky situation.

I'm trying to use default_order on a functional field (store = False, because I need to recompute the field every time a new user login).

Here my fields

```
'my_last_explanation_date': fields.function(_get_my_last_explanation_info,  string='تاريخ وتوقيت الإحالة',
                                              type='datetime',fnct_search=_my_outgoing_search),
    'my_last_stored_date':fields.datetime(string='تاريخ وتوقيت الإحالة'),
```

the function to compute both fields:

```
def _get_my_last_explanation_info(self, cr, uid, ids, fieldnames, args, context=None):
    res={}
    active_ids = []
    mail_obj = self.pool.get('mail.message')
    current_partner = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr,uid,uid).partner_id
    cr.execute('''select * from mail_message mess
            inner join messgae_sl_sender_rel rel on mess.id = rel.message_id
            and rel.sender_id = %s
            and mess.sl_status not in ('draft','canceled','archived')
            and mess.sl_create = 't'
            and mess.type in ('internal','external','export')
            order by mess.id'''%(uid))
    active_ids = [elem[0] for elem in cr.fetchall()]
    if len(ids) == 1:
        active_ids = ids
    for id in active_ids:
        cr.execute('''select forw.create_date from slnee_mail_message_forward forw
            inner join mail_message mess on forw.sl_mail_message_id = mess.id
                where mess.id = %s
                and forw.sl_sender_id = %s
                order by forw.create_date DESC '''%(id,current_partner.id))
        res_query = cr.fetchone() or False
        res[id] = res_query[0] if res_query else False
        mail_obj.write(cr,uid,[id],{'my_last_stored_date':res[id]})
    return res
```

and the XML

```
<record id="out_going_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">out_going.tree</field>
        <field name="model">mail.message</field>
        <field name="priority">20</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Messages" edit="false" create="false" duplicate="false" delete="false" class="oe_tree_view" default_order="my_last_stored_date"
             row_classes="new-msg:to_read==True; new-signed:speech_state=='unsigned'; users-copie:is_copie_users==True ; secret-mail:sl_secret==True ;  generalisation-mail:sl_generalization==True " >
                <field name="type"  string="الصنف" width="5%"/>
                <field name="name"  string="رقم المعاملة" width="5%"/>
                <field name="my_last_stored_date" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="my_last_explanation_date"  width="20%"/>
                <field name="subject" string="الموضوع" width="55%" widget="tag"
                      first_text=" سري " second_text=" عاجل " 
                      first_class="tags secret-tag" second_class="tags urgent-tag"
                      attrs="{'first_condition': [('sl_secret','=',True)],'second_condition': [('sl_periority_haut','=',True)]}"/>
                <field name="instruction_reciever_id"  />
                <field name="reciever_id"   width="5%"/>
                <field name="sl_status" width="5%" />
                <field name="sl_periority_haut" invisible="1" />
                <field name="to_read" invisible="1" />
                <field name="sl_secret" invisible="1" />
                <field name="instruction_name" invisible="1"  />
                <field name="sl_generalization" invisible="1"  />
                <field name="speech_state" invisible="1" />
                <field name="is_copie_users" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I use the function of one field to write on another and i try to use the second field for order , the problem is that the user can see the updates only after refresh.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output